# Multiple # delays in SystemVerilog code (10:20:40)

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

In my SystemVerilog code, I have a `timeunit` of `1ns` and `timeprecision` of `10ps`. 
I have my "output" defined as `logic`.

```
always@(condition)  
    begin
        #2          output = 1'b1;  // I know this makes output high after 2nS.  
        #(10:20:40) output = 1'b0;  // What does this statement do ?  
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2012, section 11.12 *Minimum, typical, and maximum delay expressions*:

```
min:typ:max
```

During a given simulation, one of the 3 values will be used for the delay.  It is my experience that simulators use the middle value (`typ`) by default.  In that case, the "output" signal would be high for 20ns.

Simulators I've used provide runtime command-line options for selecting one of the 3 delays, such as:

```
+mindelays
+typdelays
+maxdelays
```

If you run the simulation with `+maxdelays`, the "output" signal would be high for 40ns.

---

Note that `output` is a reserved keyword in Verilog and can't be used as a signal name.  Something like `out` would be a legal signal name.